# Cannot compile C code because ip_icmp.h uses types "u_int32_t" and "n_short"

Tags: c, networking, ip, protocols

Cannot compile C code: my code has #include and ip_icmp.h uses types "u_int32_t" and "n_short" that the compiler cannot read. I can't modify ip_icmp.h to change the types, and don't think I should anyways. Did I forget to install a package of some sort?

Comment: More likely you forgot to include some other file.

Comment: #include sys/cdefs.h and #include sys/types.h